# What module do the class `Hash`, `Array`, `File` belong to?

Tags: ruby

Simple question:

What module do the class `Hash`, `Array`, `File` belong to ?

Would you just say that they are part of the ruby core?

Comment: Yes, they are part of ruby core and/or stdlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to the simple question is **Yes** they are part of **[Ruby Core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/)**

Answer (score 2):

They are instances of the `Class` module (class).

Answer (score 2):

Classes don't "belong to modules". They are just objects like any other object. If you are asking about the *constants* `Hash`, `Array`, `File`, etc., those belong to the `Object` class. All constants that are not explicitly defined in some specific module belong to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Hash, Array, File they all belongs to core.